# How to check does ElementArrayFinder contains substring

Tags: protractor, chai

I've got an `ElementArrayFinder` which contains of an entire row of a table.
I'd like to make an assertion to check whether it has an substring (it does not matter where).

`const row: ElementArrayFinder = $$('div > div#myRow');`

Resolved promise of `row.getText()` returns:

`['id', 'some data', 'expected text xoxo', 'some more data']`

---

The closest solution:

`expect(row.getText()).to.eventually.deep.includes('expected text');`

returns:
`AssertionError: expected [ Array(4) to deep include 'expected text']`

---

`expect(row.getText()).to.eventually.deep.includes('expected text xoxo');`

passes

---

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to avoid misunderstandings - elementArrayFinder may not have text values of elements. The best way to think of it is elementFinder is a reference how to find your element on the page (just direction)

Now, since you are able to `.getText()` of your elementArrayFinder now it's very easy to do what you're are trying to do. But before that keep in mind that previous answer will only work if an element of your array is exactly equals to your `'expected text'`. For instance,

```
expect('expected text xoxo', 'some more data']).toContain('expected text xoxo') // this succeed
expect('expected text xoxo', 'some more data']).toContain('expected text') // this fails
// because 'expected text xoxo' !== 'expected text'
```

But if you want to check if any element of they array partially contains a string, then use vanilla js [array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
let arr = ['id', 'some data', 'expected text xoxo', 'some more data'];
expect(arr.some((item)=>{return item.includes('expected text')})).toBe(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through chai's documentation and it seems to be impossible.

I can see two ways for solving my issue:

1. Resolve a promise to `string[]` and then iterate through each element and check using `.includes('expected text')`.
2. Use protractor's `filter()` on `ElementArrayFinder` with `getText()` on each element. Use if statement to check `.includes('expected text')`, and check is length of new `ElementArrayFinder` longer than 0.